# Hiding elements without a glitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have to hide some rows of a `<table>` which will contain specific words. I'm searching for these rows by using the `:contains` selector from jQuery and using  `.hide()`.

The problem is that it results in an unpleasant glitter showing those rows momentarily before they hide.

Is there an possibility of reducing that glitter, or bind some event to the document which will analyze each DOM element upon creation and not rendering them if the will meet some requirements?

Comment: How about showing a snippet of code you are currently using?

Comment: So you want these rows hidden from the start? Is that correct? By "glitter" do you mean that they are briefly visible before hiding?

Comment: You can reduce the chance of it happening by moving your code outside of the DOMReady event and placing it before the closing body tag, however in slower browsers you may still see the FOUC("glitter"). The only way to prevent it completely is to hide it with something other than javascript, or to hide the entire table until you are done manipulating it.

Answer (score 0):

Most templating engines will do what you want, allowing you to add some logic to decide whether or not to create an element in the first place.

Another option would be to have your table hidden from the start (in CSS `display:none`), run your jQuery to find the rows you want to hide (or even remove) and only then use jQuery to make your table visible (with `.show()`). The downside to this approach is that it doesn't degrade gracefully if you have a visitor without JavaScript enabled. They won't ever be able to see the table!

Of course, if you don't have JavaScript enabled, you won't be able to hide the rows on the client side either. You'd have to handle it on the server side.